# Does SauceLabs or Browserstack support testing chinese browsers? If not what tool should I go for?

Tags: browser-automation, cross-browser-testing

Testing an application, for both desktop and mobile, aiming the Chinese market. 
I need to conduct cross-browser testing on some of the most popular chinese browsers like QQ , 360, UC, Baidu browsers and was wondering if any of the cloud based cross-browser testing tools, like SauceLabs or Browserstack, support these browsers? If not, is there any recommendation on which tool to choose from?
P.S: I would still want to continue my cross browser testing on other popular browsers like Chrome, Firefox, etc.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I see, `BrowserStack` does not support the browsers you've mentioned, here is a [full table of supported systems and browsers](https://www.browserstack.com/list-of-browsers-and-platforms?product=automate).

Same goes for Sauce Labs, here is a [full list of what the service supports](https://saucelabs.com/platforms).

I guess you should explore the option of having your own selenium server with selenium nodes for your desired browsers, assuming these browsers can be automated with selenium - meaning, have available drivers.